# Does restoring temporal table database also restore the history tables to an earlier state?

Tags: sql-server

Usually auditing is done through triggers, however I have created       temporal tables for my database, so that I can do data forensics as      well auditing. I also have an auditing requirement, that is , if I       were to restore my database to an earlier state, the audit data(       history table) needs to be kept intact and only the original table       needs to be restored. The history tables remain same regardless the     restoration point.

One way that i can achieve this is turning off the system versioning off and then restore the original tables and again turn the system versioning on. This seems really hectic task to to for every tables since I got about 500-1000 tables that i need to audit.

One more query, If temporal tables aren't good for auditing ,should I go for traditional Triggers for data auditing then?

Comment: sounds like a bit of an illogical requirement. If you restore the data to an earlier state, then anything that happened after that time is destroyed and no longer exists. Why then would you want to retain an audit trail of changes which now no longer exist? Effectively, those changes didn't happen, so why keep a record of them? What would it prove?

Comment: However, if you really do want to do that, the easiest thing I can think of would be to store the audit data in a separate database (and maybe, for extra resilience, on another server). Then if you restore the main database, the data in the audit one cannot be affected.

Comment: If someone restored the database to an earlier state , lets day 5 days earlier .
Any transaction happened during that 5 days also get restored. However that restoration  was done in order to avoid taxes ad frauds. One would not know unless we have audit trail for that.

Comment: Yes I know If I store audit data in a separate database, I can achieve that but in my case I am using Temporal tables. And I don't  think History tables can be maintained in different database

Comment: "However that restoration was done in order to avoid taxes ad frauds". Who would be doing such a restoration? Surely you have change control processes and only a small number of approved, trusted people able to do such a restoration? And if this fraudulent person has sufficient access and permission such that they can restore the database, what is to stop them from erasing the audit trail as well, even if you took steps to retain it initially? IMO your requirement needs a bit more thought from a business perspective before you worry about the technical issues.

Comment: Your point is valid, however its an requirement not from our business but an government body, Inland Revenue Department (IRD) . We need our software to get IRD certified.

Comment: I would say the correct way to proceed is to put processes and procedures in place such that this fraudulent restoration cannot occur without it being documented and noticed by others in the business. From a technical perspective, keep off-site backups (via replication to another data centre, or physical tapes, or whatever) _at least_ daily which include the audit trail. That way if someone restores it back and destroys the production audit trail, you can restore the most recent backup elsewhere in order to examine the trail. You can have live replication going on every few minutes if need be.